# UI/Acceptance/Integration тестирование iOS-приложений

Tags: android, uiautomation, ios, test-automation

Здравствуйте,

**Я хочу узнать о том, чем на практике различаются между существующие решения для тестирования мобильных приложений.**

Как показывает заголовок этого топика, я имею в виду не unit-тестирование, а именно black box тестирование работы всего приложения целиком: этот вид тестирования обычно называется Acceptance или Integration Testing или еще иногда его называют просто "тестирование UI".

Вот существующие решения, о которых я знаю:

- [Apple UI Automation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/UsingtheAutomationInstrument/UsingtheAutomationInstrument.html)
- [Frank](https://github.com/moredip/Frank) / [Calabash](https://github.com/calabash/calabash-ios)
- [KIF](https://github.com/kif-framework/KIF)
- [ios-driver](http://ios-driver.github.io/ios-driver/index.html)
- [Appium](http://appium.io/)

(если интересно, я собрал все эти библиотеки [здесь](https://github.com/stanislaw/iOS-Projects-Catalogue#test-automation)).

Буду признателен, если кто-то поделится опытом использования любого из этих решений применительно к не-малым проектам на iOS.

---

Попробую перечислить пункты, по которым, как я предполагаю, можно сравнить эти решения:

**Язык, на котором пишутся сценарии**

- UI Automation использует Javascript (странно!).
- Frank/Calabash основаны на Ruby/Cucumber (ОК для тех, у кого есть Ruby/Rails бэкграунд).
- KIF - Objective-C (Хорошо, ибо нативно!).
- ios-driver - Java (WTF?).
- Appium ([сразу несколько](https://github.com/appium/appium/tree/master/sample-code/examples), но в первую очередь Ruby и Javascript).

**Удобство интеграции**

- UI Automation - часть Apple Instruments, поэтому вроде как все должно быть хорошо.
- Frank/Calabash - встраиваются через кастомизацию основного таргета приложения, с этим вроде можно помириться. В основной таргет встраивается HTTP-сервер, который слушает инструкции от Cucumber и заставляет приложение им подчиняться (нажатия кнопок, заполнения текстовых полей, свайпы итд).
- KIF - через конфигурацию тестового таргета. ОК.
- ios-driver, Appium - ?

**Использование VCR Tools**

VCR Tools, например [VCRURLConnection](https://github.com/dstnbrkr/VCRURLConnection), позволяют записывать все сетевое взаимодействие при реальном обходе сценария вручную, а потом проигрывать записанное с JSON-кассеты при прогоне тестового сценария.

Мне представляется, что, например, UI Automation будет не очень-то просто подружить с такой практикой, когда используется VCR.

Буду рад услышать о таком опыте использования VCR.

**Хорошая поддержка доступа к view-иерархии и хорошая поддержка основных жестов (swipes и др.)**

Наверное, лучше всего это должно быть у UI Automation, и, наверное, и в остальных решения все это должно быть более-менее в наличии.

Опять же буду рад, если кто-то опишет ограничения, с которыми пришлось столкнуться в работе с тем или иным решением.

**Кроссплатформенность**

- UI Automation (хм, только Apple)
- Frank (вроде только iOS), Calabash (iOS, Android и скорее всего Windows, так как автор Calabash работает в Xamarin)
- KIF (только Objective-C/iOS)
- ios-driver (вроде только iOS)
- Appium (iOS, Android)

Будет интересно, если кто-то поделиться опытом разработки сценариев сразу под две или более платформ!

**Настройка CI-серверов**

Здесь от себя ничего не напишу, так как еще ни разу этим не занимался, но подозреваю, что по этому пункту тоже могут быть значительные различия (легкость, удобство).

---

Подчеркну, что буду признателен за развёрнутые ответы. Интересует реальный опыт использования этих решений: удобство, проблемы, достоинства/недостатки - словом, всё, что сможет мне и другим потенциальным читателям этого топика определиться с тем, какое решение предпочтительнее использовать.

**P.S.** Я сам склоняюсь к KIF или Calabash.

**P.S. #2** По слухам известно, что Яндекс использует в некоторых iOS-проектах Calabash и CI.

---

**ОБНОВЛЕНО ПОЗЖЕ**

Я принимаю замечательный ответ Дмитрия, как верный, и это не означает, что тема закрыта: если Вам есть что рассказать, можете поделиться опытом, как это сделал Дмитрий, - прошу, обязательно пишите ваши ответы, так как эта тема интересна мне и, наверное, всем тем из из нас, кто связан с iOS-, да и вообще мобильной разработкой :)

Comment: Было бы здорово, если на ХК можно было подписаться на вопросы/ответы от конкретного юзера :)

Comment: @AlexDenisov, спасибо. Я старался. Тема горячая и темная одновременно.

Comment: Я в принципе не против быть первопроходцем в качественном, как это сейчас любят поговаривать, "промышленном", освоении всей этой темы, просто хочется хоть немного заручиться чьими-то опытом, советами и указаниями, прежде чем нырять в эту тему.

Comment: Стас, а че не на хабре? :)

Comment: @Bimawa, а где там на Хабре? Я может быть не в курсе?

Comment: @AlexDenisov http://take.ms/HL2W9 вообще то можно

Comment: @Andreich, спасибо, это я упустил.

Но мое желание немного иного рода - меня интересуют все вопросы конкретного пользователя.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Привет.

Делал сравнение в конце прошлого года: http://www.slideshare.net/dmitrycheremushkin/appium-sqa-days-15-2014/8
Но для меня были важны Java и поддержка WebDriver API, приоритетна кроссплатформенность. Поскольку это была интеграция мобильного решения в существующий фреймворк.

На текущий момент есть опыт использования Appium и Calabash.

---

*Внесу ясность по нескольким вопросам:*

##### *Язык, на котором пишутся сценарии; Удобство интеграции*

> ios-driver - Java (WTF?).
> Appium (сразу несколько, но в первую очередь Ruby и Javascript).

ios-driver и Appium преобразуют WebDriver API запросы (от тестов) в команды UI Automation:

- [How Appium works](http://www.slideshare.net/saucelabs/appium-basic-20296603)
- [How ios-driver works](http://www.slideshare.net/davidodowd/ios-driver-presentation-copy/11)

Серверная часть в них — это Selenium-сервер с поддержкой некоторых дополнительных команд. Отсюда поддержка такого количества языков для написания тестов.

##### *Хорошая поддержка доступа к view-иерархии и хорошая поддержка основных жестов (swipes и др.)*

Здесь могу сказать только про Appium — у них всё, что нужно поддерживается ([Appium's gestures](https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/0.18.x/docs/en/gestures.md)), при этом они достаточно часто вносят улучшения и выполняют запросы пользователей. Из примеров, недавно был добавлен direction в scrollTo.

У Appium есть GUI-инспектор элементов, сейчас должен работать достаточно стабильно. Через него же можно записывать сценарий — кликаешь по элементам, генерится код.

##### *Кроссплатформенность*

> Calabash (iOS, Android и скорее всего Windows, так как автор Calabash работает в Xamarin)

Calabash — только Android и iOS, Windows Phone не поддерживается

> Appium (iOS, Android)

Appium — iOS, Android и FirefoxOS

##### *Настройка CI-серверов*

Здесь важно понимать масштаб. :)
Простой случай — когда нужно проверить одно приложение, пусть на нескольких версиях ОС, но когда нет сильных временных ограничений.
И другое дело — если нужно делать распределённый запуск, а то и полноценный мобильный CI, для нескольких приложений с несколькими платформами, версиями, устройствами.

В первом случае — по сути подойдёт любое из перечисленных решений. Нужен лишь CI, умеющий запускать shell-скрипт и в случае с iOS — работающий на Mac OS, либо включающий агенты на Mac OS.

Во втором случае —

1. либо распределять запуск с
       помощью нативных CI-агентов
2. либо включать мобильные ноды в
       Selenium Grid (поддерживается
       ios-driver и Appium)
3. либо
       написать свою реализацию, если
       позволяет инструментарий — зависит
       прежде всего от того, как он
       работает с устройствами/эмуляторами
       "внутри" и позволяет ли их
       инициализировать (знаю, что c
       Calabash так можно сделать)

2 и 3 — можно распределять не по сьютам, а по отдельным тестам, это преимущество + меньше нагрузки на CI

---

##### *Ещё мысли*

- Не знаю, как с UI Automation, но с
     использованием других средств
     можно построить полноценный фреймворк
     — с аналогом Page Objects, BDD,
     репортингом и пр.
- Appium и ios-driver особенно хороши, если уже имеются веб-тесты и требуется их погонять в мобильных браузерах. Из них я для себя выбрал Appium, т.к. лучше поддержка, развивается интенсивней и кроссплатформенен.
- Насколько я знаю, в Яндексе в основном используют Appium
  (источник: http://www.slideshare.net/yandex/ss-28743339)

Comment: Дмитрий, большое спасибо за ответ!

Answer (score 6):

Позволю себе процитировать пару ответов, которые я получил по другим источникам, чтобы насытить этот топик контентом:

> Мы у себя пробовали Frank и KIF. Frank пробовали года полтора назад, и тогда он показался немного сыроватым. С тех пор они, насколько я знаю, перешли на KIF-овский движок и многое допилили, но я лично не юзал. В принципе, если есть бэкграунд на руби, это отличное решение. Ну а KIF - лучшее решение для суровых iOS-ников :)
>
> А если немного отойти вбок от темы, то сейчас набирают популярность MVVM-подобные темы, которые позволяют полностью протестировать UI без, собственно, самого UI
> https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveViewModel вот тут немного инфы

---

> Мы использовали KIF.
>
> Еще нашими QA использовался Appium — форк от селениума
> но KIF как-то оказался проще в реализации. Нативный.
> Проблема только в том, что приходится для его впиливания делать изменения в самом коде (впиливать лэйблы контролам).
>
> `>` На практике у нас всегда на проектах ручное тестирование применялось. Хотябы потому, что UI постоянно апдейтится, темпы разработки и изменений довольно быстрые а экранов много.
>
> Тут прелесть KIF в том, что не зависимо от географического положения контрола, фреймворк находит его именно по лэйблу. По сему изменения в лэйауте, как правило, не ломают тесты

---

Еще один лаконичный ответ:

> UI testing sucks : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h1TRkDSmnOc

Comment: @Stanislaw Pankevich, просим законченый отчет ввиде статьи, простите за наглость ^_^

Comment: @Bimawa, я бы с радостью, только хочу собрать __больше обратной связи__ и сделать какие собственные пробы на эту тему.

Comment: Drew дело в общем-то говорит.

* UI тесты врут, что нет бага
* UI тесты переписывать на 90% приходится от релиза к релизу, нет пожизненных тестов, что раз написал и забыл.
* под UI тесты возможно придется ломать интерфейс, потому что протестить все варианты поведения одного input'а не всегда получается
* ...

ну и по мелочи, типа ios тестить на руби не всякий будет...

и да, если вы написали tdd-тесты с полным или хорошим покрытием, займитесь лучше bdd-тестами, они скажут больше и эффективность по деньги+время будет выше. и потом, даже плохой QA в итоге будет выгоднее, не говоря уж о хорошем.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, спасибо за TLDR для этого видео. Я сам его пока что не смотрел, но примерно такое и ожидал услышать.